# Using MySQL, join two tables by updating the values in the result table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:

```
create table songs
(song_id int not null primary key auto_increment
, song_name varchar(500)
);

create table genre_tag_information
(singer_id int primary key not null auto_increment
, song_id int
, genre_tag varchar(20)
, tagged_role varchar(20)
, foreign key(song_id) references songs(song_id)
);

insert into songs (song_name)
values
('abcd')
, ('efgh')
, ('ijkl')
, ('mnop');

insert into genre_tag_information (song_id, genre_tag, tagged_role)
values
(1, 'folk', 'director')
, (1, 'folk', 'asst_director')
, (1, 'folk','asst_director')
, (2, 'classic', 'asst_director')
, (2, 'classic', 'asst_director')
, (2, 'melody', 'asst_director')
, (4, 'rock', 'asst_director')
, (4, 'jazz', 'asst_director')
, (4, 'bass', 'asst_director');
```

There are some set of rules given to obtain the result. They are as follows

**Set of conditions:**

1. Pick the tag of a director if it's there for a song and ignore tags by asst_directors
2. For a given song only one director tag record
   would be there
3. For a given song, 3 tag records can be there by
   asst_directors. So total 4 records max if no director tag is available then pick the tag which was provided by more than 1 tagged_role.
4. If all editors have provided diff tag in tagged role then show 'MIX-GENRE' as the tagged_role so that director can review and fix.
5. If there is only one asst_director record then we can show that tag directly.

I tried the below query. But I am unable to satisfy all given conditions

**Solution I tried:**

```
select songs.song_id, 
       song_name, 
       genre_tag,
       case when genre_tag is null 
            then ''
            when tagged_role='director' 
            then 'director'
            when (count(distinct genre_tag) > 1) 
            then (select max(tagged_role) 
                  from genre_tag_information)
            when tagger_role <> 'director' and (count(distinct genre_tag)) = 1 
            then tagged_role
            else 'no entry'
            end as 'director_action_role'
from sentenses
left join tags on tags.sentense_id = sentenses.sentense_id
group by tags.song_id;
```

**Output expected:**

**song_id | song_name | genre_tag  | director_tag_role |**

```
 1    |  abcd     |  folk      |  director       |  
 2    |  efgh     |  classic   |  asst_director  |  
 3    |  ijkl     |            |                 |      
 4    |  mnop     |  mix_genre |  asst_director< |
```

Comment: Why genre_tag for song_id=2 is classic whereas it has 'melody' tag additionally?

Comment: It seems so unlikely that a pk would be formed on a column called singer_id as to make the rest of the question implausible

Comment: I'd prefer 4 subqueries and UNION ALL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT song_id, 
                 genre_tag, 
                 tagged_role, 
                 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY song_id, tagged_role, genre_tag) cnt
          FROM genre_tag_information
          ORDER BY song_id ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT song_id, 
                 genre_tag, 
                 tagged_role, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY song_id ORDER BY tagged_role = 'director' DESC, cnt ASC) rn,
                 MAX(cnt > 1) OVER (PARTITION BY song_id) mix
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT songs.song_id,
       songs.song_name,
       CASE WHEN cte2.mix IS NULL
            THEN ''
            WHEN cte2.mix = 1
            THEN cte2.genre_tag
            ELSE 'mixed' 
            END genre_tag, 
       COALESCE(cte2.tagged_role, '') tagged_role
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON songs.song_id = cte2.song_id AND rn = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ede18a831e86e9853971e0c858a61e76